# FullCalendar: can I change 'end' property name in event object? 'end' is reserved

Tags: json, fullcalendar

I am learning FullCalendar JS plugin by Adam Shaw. And first at all I want to say "Thanks a lot" to the plugin author.

I am trying to pass events by JSON string from back to JS. And everything works great.

But suddenly I'm faced with a problem.

Calendar expects the event object in a certain format, for example there is an 'end' property for end time. And I created a special class in back-code, and an array of that class instance is serialized to JSON string (which is passed to the front).

But I can not create a property with name 'end' in my back code class! 'end' name is reserved there.

Not sure what to do.

Comment: I got an idea: probably I need to 're-write' objects retrieved from JSON string to new objects with right format on client side and pass to Calendar new objects. Thanks

Comment: I have written an anonymous function where I just create new Property 'end' in the array of event objects and pass to it a value:  events:  (function(){ SOME CODE })() // AND DON'T PUT ; here!!!

Comment: What language you use in backend so that you cant use "end"?

Comment: APEX (Salesforce's language, it is close to JAVA)

Comment: Denis your first thought is correct in my point of view, since that's a reserved word just change the key propertie end to something else and then on client side just change it back again.